# Delete the latest file in HDFS shell

Tags: hdfs

How can I delete the latest file using HDFS shell?

e.g. I have two files, dated `2017-01-03` and `2017-01-01`; I want to delete the `2017-01-03` one.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete with `hdfs dfs -rm /file/path`

For more [click here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#rm)